# Wordpress Contact form 7: 2 forms on one page - only one form functions

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

I have the latest version of wordpress, with the latest version of Contact Form 7.

I use 2 shortcodes/forms on one page. The issue is that only the first form works. When I hit submit on the second form, the validation works, but the validation div does yield any messages:

```
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
```

I don't really have any code to share since its so general of a problem. If I enter information that validates in the second form, the message appears to be sent (again, no response), however I never receive any email.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

because you are posting the same form name="" field, and same input names, the second form overwrites the 1st.

You need to change the form name and it should work ok.

Comment: I am looking at the settings of Contact Form 7 but can't figure out where to change the form name attribute. Any help?

Comment: He means field names should be different in both forms. Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the two forms with different classes to handle

For example:

```
Form 1 class = "form-one" 

Form 2 class = "form-two"
```